# Hexbin from D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

we are trying to use Hexbin from D3 (the preview images as honeycomb that is running as homepage right now at D3js.org) but we don't understand how the code associate an URL with each node in the json file (in others words, how the code put the URL for the right image as preview).

THANKS A LOT!
best regards from Chile

We have an image from the latest error here:
http://www.zolutiva.cl/d3/hexbin_error.png
And what are we doing is here: http://www.zolutiva.cl/d3/

THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7833311)?

Comment: Can you share some code to show us what you have tried until now. It will help to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the main image: http://d3js.org/ex.jpg?3f2d00ffdba6ced9c50f02ed42f12f6156368bd2

And below are the first lines of the json:

```
var data = [
{title: "Reingold–Tilford Tree (Radial)", url: "http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550"},
{title: "Factorisation Diagrams", url: "http://www.jasondavies.com/factorisation-diagrams/"},
{title: "Phylogenetic Tree of Life", url: "http://www.jasondavies.com/tree-of-life/"},
{title: "Geographic Clipping", url: "http://www.jasondavies.com/maps/clip/"},
{title: "Les Misérables Co-occurrence Matrix", url: "http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/"},
{title: "L*a*b* and HCL color spaces", url: "http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3014589"},
```

Note that they are in the same order (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550 correspond to the first image, http://www.jasondavies.com/factorisation-diagrams to the second...) Then they are displayed randomly.

Comment: If this solved your issue please consider to mark it as the answer

Comment: yesterday we made some trials and got some results, but the code is not working ok : we have a problem here with a variable (its definition)

Comment: We have an image from the latest error here:
http://www.zolutiva.cl/d3/hexbin_error.png
And what are we doing is here: http://www.zolutiva.cl/d3/

THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: This is a different issue, open a new question explaining it. I guess it's about the variables defined in the line #291